# Back up mysql database from java program

Tags: java, database, backup

I'm trying to backup my database from a Java application. Currently, I'm using xampp as a `localhost` for database. I tried these codes in my program, but when I execute these codes my program goes on waiting state. When I execute the same code from command line it ask a password and after giving a password back up file `backup.sql` is created successfully.
The code I'm using is:

```
String executeCmd = "C:\\xampp\\mysql\\bin\\mysqldump.exe -u root -p db1 -r D:/mine/backup.sql";
```

Java code:

```
    Process runtimeProcess;
    try {


        runtimeProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(executeCmd);

        int processComplete = runtimeProcess.waitFor();

        if (processComplete == 0) {
            System.out.println("Backup created successfully");
            return true;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Could not create the backup");
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the command with password in it, like

```
String executeCmd = "C:\\xampp\\mysql\\bin\\mysqldump.exe -u root -pYOUR_DB_PASSWORD db1 -r D:/mine/backup.sql";
```

Mind the *NO SPACE* between `-p` and the `DATABASE PASSWORD`.

---

**Edit1:** (from comment)

To resotre your database you need to execute

```
mysql -u root -pPASSWORD db1 < /full/qualified/path/to/backup.sql
```

**Edit2:** (improvements)

You may also want to try some of the cool options like

```
mysqldump --user MYSQL_USER --password=MYSQL_PASSWORD --add-locks --flush-privileges \
--add-drop-table --complete-insert --extended-insert --single-transaction \
--database DB_TO_BACKUP > FILENAME_FOR_SQL_STATEMENTS
```

Refer [here](http://code.naishe.in/2012/07/backup-your-mysql-to-amazon-s3.html).

Comment: what sud i write if the database password is ""(null).

Comment: @user1154781 -- `it ask a password and after giving a password back up file backup.sql is created successfully.` -- I thought you have a password. If there is no password, I think, you should remove `-p` option from the `executeCmd`

Comment: Hey thanx it worked and what if i had to restore this file as database in my application.

Comment: @user1154781 glad it worked. If this answer solved your problem, please mark it as answered by clicking on the up-tick next to this answer. [See here how](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). If you liked the answer, you may also up-vote by clicking on up arrow next to the answer.

Comment: I'm just a beginner so voting is forbidden to me..surely i will in near future now can u tell me how can i restore the saved backup.sql file

Comment: @user1154781 thanks. Restoring is just running the script. You can copy the content and execute in MySQL console or redirect file to `mysql` -- make sure you create the database if not existing already... I have updated the answer.

Comment: I'm trying this code to restore DB but the app goes on waiting state..
 public boolean restoreDB() {

        String executeCmd = "C:\\xampp\\mysql\\bin\\mysql -u root lms < D:/backup.sql";
        Process runtimeProcess;
     

            runtimeProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(executeCmd);

Comment: "<" doesn't work with java when i tried same code from command line it works but from application it is not working. what is the alternative way plzz help